# display array data from mongodb collection into html table, using angular cli as front-end

Tags: arrays, angular

i'm new at nodejs, mongodb, and angular cli.
I'm making a project for my college assignment, but I'm having trouble.
I want to display the arrray data from mongodb to the existing table in the agular component.

mongdb schema:

```
{
"_id" : "sensor-2",
"data" : [ 
    {
        "sensor" : {
            "intensitas" : 1,
            "arus" : 0.1
        },
        "waktu" : "June 9th - 2018, 2:26:47 AM"
    }, 
    {
        "sensor" : {
            "intensitas" : 1,
            "arus" : 0.13
        },
        "waktu" : "June 9th - 2018, 2:32:42 AM"
    }, 
    {
        "sensor" : {
            "intensitas" : 1,
            "arus" : 0.13
        },
        "waktu" : "June 9th - 2018, 2:35:16 AM"
    }
]
}
```

i want to make tabel from "data" array, like this:
[table image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjSqn.png)

sorry my engilsh bad

Answer (score 1):

model = your object

```
 <table>
  <tr *ngFor="let item of model.data">
    <td>{{item.sensor.intensitas}}</td>
    <td>{{item.sensor.arus}}</td>
    <td>{{item.waktu}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must first json parse your json data then store it in a model like DataModel then you can bind it to html with *ngFor simply.

```
`<table>`
```

`<tr *ngFor="let item of DataModel">`
`<td>{{item.key}}</td>`
`</tr>`

`</table>`

Every times {item} is one index of your array.
I hope this help you, if you had any question feel free to ask

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer, the data is get from an collection so i must get the collection by id, and i want display the data from that collection in the table,

Comment: Ok, you can store your parsed json data in your model or you can address it in *ngFor directly `*ngFor="let item of DataModel.data"`